# Why is my code printing wrong numbers in c?

Tags: arrays, c

This is my code. It is supposed to scan 2 numbers (m and n) in the first line. Then it should scan arrays in size of n. Then it should check the numbers (1 to m) if they exist in the second line or not. If they don't exist it should print the numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n;
    int i , j;
    int x[100];
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0 ;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }
    for(j = 1;j <= m;j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
        {
            if(x[i] != j)
            {
                printf("%d", j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for example:

```
input :
3 3
1 2 4
output:
4
```

It prints wrong numbers. I was expecting it to print number 4. But it prints 1122333.

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger or add more printf statements?

Comment: `if(x[i] != j)` is probably not what you intended...

Comment: You need to loop through all the values to be sure that `j` doesn't exist in the array before you print that it is absent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the print from the inner loop.  Set a flag to 0 before the loop; when you find the value in the loop, set the flag to 1 and break. After the loop, if the flag is not set, print `j`.

Comment: Other problems: Always check the return value of `scanf`. (Many functions have a return code that would tell you if it was successful or not, so you should check it.) Your `printf` format does not contain a space or newline, so all numbers are printed without any separation. `1122333` is actually `1` `1` `2` `2` `3` `3` `3`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you post the answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n;
    int i, j;
    int x[100];
    bool exists[100] = { false }; // initialize all values to false
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        exists[x[i]-1] = true; // mark the number as existing in the array
    }
    for(j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        if (!exists[j-1]) // if the number doesn't exist in the array
        {
            printf("%d ", j);
        }
    }
    printf("\n"); // add a newline at the end
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First scan the values of `m` and `n`. Then scan the array of `n` elements. If the number is not present in the array, print the number and continue with the next number.

You need to modify ur inner loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m, n;
    int x[100];
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) { // loop over the numbers 1 to m
        int found = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // loop over array x to check if i is present
            if (x[j] == i) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { // if i was not found in array x, print it to output
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It gives runtime error. I couldn't fix it.

Comment: It works for me — give or take adding `putchar('\n'):` before the `return 0;`.  The code should check that `scanf()` works as expected, but that's a refinement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are welcome to modify my code..... for better results

Comment: No need — what you've written works.  I just don't like my command-line prompt to appear on the same line as the last line of output from the program, so I printed a newline after the loop.

Comment: i see other answe has been accepted by poster of this question may be that is better solution